# Varnish, outputting ReqEnd using standard out

Tags: varnish, varnishncsa

Is it possible to output [ReqEnd](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/Varnishlog) using std.log in VCL? I would like to use ReqEnd in varnishncsa logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra flags to the `varnishncsa` output to make it display some more information including some of the timings reported by ReqEnd, see the [documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishncsa.html), specifically the `-F format` option:

```
Supported formatters are:

... snip ...

%t
Time when the request was received, in HTTP date/time format.

%{X}t
Time when the request was received, in the format specified by X. The time specification format is the same as for strftime(3).

%{X}x

  Varnish:time_firstbyte
  Time to the first byte from the backend arrived

  Varnish:hitmiss
  Whether the request was a cache hit or miss. Pipe and pass are considered misses.

  Varnish:handling
  How the request was handled, whether it was a cache hit, miss, pass, pipe or error.

  VCL_Log:key
  Output value set by std.log("key:value") in VCL.
```